# Chrome "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined." when inserting script tag

Tags: javascript

I insert script this way

```
s = '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="'+src+'"></scr'+'ipt>';
doc.document.write(s);
```

In FF and IE it works well, but in Chrome and Opear this script doesn't loading. I checked headers and paramters in FF and Chrome. They are identical. What can it be?

Comment: Does it work if you insert the script tag in the source, instead of using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your server is properly setting the mime type of JS files in the http headers? Servers mostly seem to use the following Apache rule: AddType application/x-javascript .js

Comment: what *should* the MIME type be set to?  i'd like to double check our Apache setup so we don't hit this problem.  WR!